# Spring Boot insert sample data into database upon startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What is the right way for creating test data upon server startup and inserting them into the database (I'm using a JPA/JDBC backed Postgres instance).

Preferably in form of creating Entities and having them persisted through a Repository interface rather than writing plain SQL code. Something like RoR's `Rake db:seed` helper.

If the framework exposes a hook for doing stuff when all the beans have been injected and the database is ready, that could also work.

Comment: Don't forget to accept /upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can catch `ApplicationReadyEvent` then insert demo data, for example:

```java
@Component
public class DemoData {

    @Autowired
    private final EntityRepository repo;

    @EventListener
    public void appReady(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

        repo.save(new Entity(...));
    }
}
```

Or you can implement `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner`, to load demo data when an application is fully started:

```java
@Component
public class DemoData implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private final EntityRepository repo;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {

        repo.save(new Entity(...));
    }
}

@Component
public class DemoData implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private final EntityRepository repo;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        repo.save(new Entity(...));
    }
}
```

Or even implement them like a Bean right in your Application (or other 'config') class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demoData(EntityRepository repo) {
        return args -> { 

            repo.save(new Entity(...));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `@Autoware` annotation supposed to be `@Autowired`?

Comment: And what if I want to impersonate o user because for example I have secured methods? Can you update your example?

Answer (score 8):

From Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-database-initialization

> **Initialize a database using Hibernate**
>   A file named *import.sql* in the root of the classpath will be executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop). This can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful, but probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production. It is a Hibernate feature (nothing to do with Spring).

Comment: What is meant by root of the classpath ? the root of the src folder ? cause I think this definition is rather dependent on the build tool/platform.

Comment: If you are using Maven, then a folder like: /src/main/resources @Parsoa

Comment: Thanks. Anyway this approach seems quite error prone and time consuming for the amount of data I need to insert. I'd like it better if there was a Java solution.

Comment: This is the only solution to what you are trying to achieve according to spring boot documentation

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class H2Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(H2Application.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        CommandLineRunner init (StudentRepo studentRepo){
            return args -> {
                List<String> names = Arrays.asList("udara", "sampath");
                names.forEach(name -> studentRepo.save(new Student(name)));
            };
        }
    }
```