# Different ways to run custom code before the application starts

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Could you describe different ways to run custom code before the application starts for data initialization or something else?
(like `ApplicationListener`, `CommandLineRunner` etc.)

What is the difference between all of them? Which cases is better to use each of them in?
I want to know not only one way to do that but an understanding when and what I need to use.

Here is enough old question with too many options to do that: [Running code after Spring Boot starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts)

If it is a wrong place to ask this question, please, point me to the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What options I know:

1. CommandLineRunner - receive command-line arguments as String

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @Component
   public class DemoCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

       @Override
       public void run(String... args) {
           log.info("[CommandLineRunner] Args: " + Arrays.toString(args));
       }
   }
   ```
2. ApplicationRunner - receive command-line arguments with names

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @Component
   public class DemoApplicationRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

       @Override
       public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
           log.info("[ApplicationRunner] Args: ");
           nonOptionArgs(args);
           optionArgs(args);
       }

       private void nonOptionArgs(ApplicationArguments args) {
           args.getNonOptionArgs().forEach(log::info);
       }

       private void optionArgs(ApplicationArguments args) {
           args.getOptionNames().stream()
                   .map(args::getOptionValues)
                   .map(Objects::toString)
                   .forEach(log::info);
       }
   }
   ```
3. ApplicationListener - listener for different events (for each event own class)

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @Component
   public class DemoApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

       @Override
       public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
           logEvent(event);
       }

       private void logEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
           log.info("[DemoApplicationListener] Event: " + event);
       }
   }
   ```
4. @EventListener - listener for different events (several events in one bean)

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @Component
   public class DemoEventApplicationListener {

       @EventListener
       public void handleContextRefreshedEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
           logEvent(event);
       }

       @EventListener
       public void handleApplicationReadyEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
           logEvent(event);
       }

       private void logEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
           log.info("[DemoEventApplicationListener] Event: " + event);
       }
   }
   ```
5. SmartLifecycle - configure bean lifecycle

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @Component
   public class DemoSmartLifecycle implements SmartLifecycle {

       private boolean isRunning;

       @Override
       public void start() {
           isRunning = true;
           log.info("[DemoSmartLifecycle]: Start");
       }

       @Override
       public void stop() {
           isRunning = false;
           log.info("[DemoSmartLifecycle]: Stop");
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isRunning() {
           return isRunning;
       }
   }
   ```
6. SmartInitializingSingleton - triggered at the end of the singleton pre-instantiation phase

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @Component
   public class DemoSmartInitializingSingleton implements SmartInitializingSingleton {

       @Override
       public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
           log.info("[SmartInitializingSingleton] afterSingletonsInstantiated");
       }
   }
   ```

Github repo: https://github.com/venkaDaria/demo-bootstrap-spring

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run some code "**once the `SpringApplication` has started**" you should use `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` - they work [the same way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner).

`ApplicationListener`, or `@EventListener` with `ApplicationReadyEvent` do the same as well.

See my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754394/5380322).

The option you choose is up to you.

Comment: What about SmartLifecycle and other ways?
So, does it depend only on my preferences?

Comment: @DariaPydorenko I didn't use it. But I think SmartLifecycle is a [bit more redundant option](http://selvakumaresra.herokuapp.com/spring-smartlifecycle-smart-shutdown-sequence-for-java-service/) than others if you need just run some code 'once the SpringApplication has started'.